# Duplicate the value in SQL inner join,

Tags: sql

I write the SQL query for take some value in my db using SQL Server 2019

**My SQL query**

```
select 
    
    '' as 'Project Code', 
    client.CLI_NAME as 'Plant', 
    issue.ISU_CODE as 'Log ID' ,
    issue.ISU_DESCRIPTION  as 'Description',
    issue.ISS_CODE as 'Status',
    issue.MOD_CODE as 'Module Name',
    issue.ISU_COMMENT as 'Comment',
    issue.USR_CODE_LOG as 'Loged User',
    issue.ISU_REPORT_DATE as 'Reported Date',
    issue.ISC_CODE as 'Issue Type',
    issue.ISU_CLOSED_DATE as 'Solve Date',
    severiry.SEV_NAME as 'Serverity Level',
    '' as 'Follow up Comment',
    CONCAT(eng_allow.LOG_DATE,'-',sys_user.USR_NAME,'-',eng_allow.COMMENT) as 'Engineer Allocation Comment'

from 
    [eSUPPORT].[HS_SP_ISSUE] as issue
inner join 
    [eSUPPORT].[HS_SP_CLIENT_SITE] as cli_site
on
    issue.CLS_CODE=cli_site.CLS_CODE
inner join
    [eSUPPORT].[HS_SP_CLIENT] as client
on
    cli_site.CLI_CODE=client.CLI_CODE
inner join
    [eSUPPORT].[HS_SP_ENGINEER_ALLOCATION] as eng_allow
on
    issue.ISU_CODE=eng_allow.ISU_CODE 


inner join
    [eSUPPORT].[HS_SP_SYSTEM_USER] as sys_user
on
    eng_allow.USR_CODE=sys_user.USR_CODE
inner join
    [eSUPPORT].[HS_SP_SEVERITY] as severiry
on
    issue.SEV_CODE=severiry.SEV_CODE

where
    issue.ISU_CODE='060307'
```

**once I execute the query output seams like (Value is duplicating)**

[image]

because of the **[eSUPPORT].[HS_SP_ENGINEER_ALLOCATION]** table

```
select * from [eSUPPORT].[HS_SP_ENGINEER_ALLOCATION]  where ISU_CODE='060307'
```

[image: HS_SP_ENGINEER_ALLOCATION table output]

in this

> [eSUPPORT].[HS_SP_ENGINEER_ALLOCATION]

table

> ISU_CODE='060307'

have two values
***how to take first value***

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 2):

SQL tables represent *unordered* sets.  There is no such thing as the "first value" unless a column specifies the ordering.  Let me speculate that the column is `iss_code`.

You can replace the table with a subquery that enumerates the rows for each `isu_code`:

```
(select ea.*,
        row_number() over (partition by isu_code order by iss_code) as seqnum
 from [eSUPPORT].[HS_SP_ENGINEER_ALLOCATION] ea
) eng_allow
on issue.ISU_CODE = eng_allow.ISU_CODE and eng_allow.seqnum = 1
```

Comment: Thank you so much **@GordonLinof**

Answer (score 1):

Not sure you will always get the first value (or the one with the comment you want) but a workaround would be something like this

```
inner join (select distinct a, b 
    from Mytable) 
on...
```